# Variable doesn't change to last input for that variable

Tags: c++

I am trying to make this program currently output the character that they enter, after they enter an error. Currently if you enter a wrong character, I usually just do z, it will give you the desired out of "Error! Please enter a correct type!" and then go back to the start and have you enter the value again. If you enter lower case p it will then prompt for amount of checks written, i usually just say 1. After the checks written input it will then finish by outputting the Account Type that you entered. The problem I am getting is it outputs the z that I entered first and not the p.

How do I go about making the output of the Account Type the last input for that variable. (Global variables aren't allowed)

Code is this:
http://pastebin.com/1DrNcmrR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Jumping right back to the top of the function is bad practice, I woulnd't recommend trying to solve errors by calling the function again, instead how about you enter a while until the input is good?

```
while(true) {
    cin >> answer;
    if(toupper(answer) == 'P' || toupper(answer) == 'C') //#include <cctype>
        break;
    cout << "Error! Please enter a correct type!" << endl;
}

//switch, no default needed
```

Comment: while that may be better, the project is required to have a switch statement. and I also very new to c++ (in the basic c++ class for CSC) and I don't fully understand the code that you wrote and wouldn't want to use code that I don't understand.

Is there a better way to loop in the switch statement? could I have a separate function that made the accountType function run again?

Comment: @AndréFecteau well have you learned any looping yet? If you look at my code it says you still run a switch statement below, this just ensures you will have good input before moving on to the switch statement.

Comment: Yeah, we have been introduced to loops but I am having a hard time understanding them. The only part i don't get is how to tell it to go back to the beginning when its not a counted loop.

Comment: I actually figured it out. The code can be found here:http://pastebin.com/z84DjK21

I added a while statement to accType.